# RATE function gives #NUM! error for a valid interval of period values

Tags: google-sheets

We are using the financial functions of Google Sheets, and for some number of periods, the `RATE` function is in error `#NUM!`, with the following message:

> RATE attempted to compute the internal rate of return for a series of
>   cash flows, but it was not able to.

This is notably the case for:

```
=rate(75; -1500; -150000; 500000)
```

Which is in error when the period values is in the range [70; 99]

Is this a bug in Google Sheet, or a known limitation?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Google Sheets' RATE function works in a similar way than the function of the same name in Excel. Excel documentation says (emphasis mine):

> Returns the interest rate per period of an annuity. RATE is calculated by iteration and can have zero or more solutions. **If the successive results of RATE do not converge to within 0.0000001 after 20 iterations, RATE returns the #NUM! error value.**

But, Excel 2016 for Windows doesn't return error.